# Kubernetes Nginx ingress : Imagepull failing with cert issue

Tags: ssl, nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, azure-aks

After installing nginx ingress from helm charts, relavent pods are not getting started as image pull is failing due to SSL issue.

Pod describe :

```
 Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From                               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----                               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  <unknown>          default-scheduler                  Successfully assigned xxx/xxxxxxx-nginx-ingress-controller-649b45b7c6-26ggh to aks-agentpool-21683929-0
  Normal   Pulling    16s (x2 over 29s)  kubelet, aks-agentpool-21683929-0  Pulling image "quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.32.0"
  Warning  Failed     16s (x2 over 29s)  kubelet, aks-agentpool-21683929-0  Failed to pull image "quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.32.0": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://quay.io/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
  Warning  Failed     16s (x2 over 29s)  kubelet, aks-agentpool-21683929-0  Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff    3s (x3 over 28s)   kubelet, aks-agentpool-21683929-0  Back-off pulling image "quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.32.0"
  Warning  Failed     3s (x3 over 28s)   kubelet, aks-agentpool-21683929-0  Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

Should I trust / ignore  the certifcate at K8s API server or in Pods, I couldnt find right info online.  Any help would greatly benefit.

Comment: What is the operating system? seems `/etc/ssl/certs` is not updated with root CA. Does `docker pull` of that image works on that kubernetes node?

Comment: Have you followed any tutorial? As far as I checked [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-own-tls#generate-tls-certificates)  `For this article, let's generate a self-signed certificate with openssl. For production use, you should request a trusted, signed certificate through a provider or your own certificate authority (CA).` Could you try with that?

Comment: Its RHEL worker nodes.